# Attempts to perform calculations using Offset give me errors (vba for excel)

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range

I want to perform some calculations on an excel sheet, which has a dataset organised as follows.

Column A --> date

Column B --> hour

Column C to lastColumn --> data

One of the columns has the name "intensity". I want to add a column at the end, which will host the sum of "intensity" values from 00:00 to 23:00 at the row where the hour is "00:00" and another column which will give me the value at row "05:00" subtracted by the value at row "22:00". This is my attempt:

```
Sub intensity_computations()

Dim k, l, intensity_column As Integer
Dim lastCol, lastRow As Long
Dim rng, start As Range

'I define the variables of the number of the last column and the last row:
lastCol = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

'I find the column number that corresponds to the column "intensity"
For k = lastCol To 1 Step -1
    If Not Cells(1, k).Find("intensity") Is Nothing Then
       intensity_column = k
    End If
Next k

'I create the column with the summed hourly values written at the the rows with hour "00:00:00"
For l = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(l, 2).Value = "00:00:00" Then
        start_cell = Cells(l, intensity_column)
        rng = Range(start_cell, start_cell.Offset(23, 0))
        Cells(l, lastCol + 1) = Application.Sum(rng)
    End If
Next l

'I create the column with the subtracted value of hour "22:00" from the value of hour "05:00", which should be written at row with hour "00:00"
For l = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(l, 2).Value = "00:00:00" Then
        Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Value = Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Offset(5, -2) - Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Offset(22, -2)
    End If
Next l

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I get errors such as "object required" or "missmatch", depending if the first For-loop is placed before or after the second For-loop.

Anyone that could help with this?

Comment: (1) You don't need the first loop, `Find` can seach the whole range (2) You need `Set` when assigning object variables `Set rng = ...` (3) You haven't declared `start_cell` (4) You can't put the first loop after the second because you define `intensity_column` in the first (5) When declaring variables you should list each type `Dim rng as Range, start As Range` etc.

Comment: (6) The third loop can be combined with the second (7) Do the cells contain text "00:00:00" or are they numbers formatted as times?

Comment: I will have a closer look to what you suggest. As for (7): the time column contains values formatted as times and not text. In the excel sheet, I can set the if statement as if(hour("cell address")=0, ......, ""), but VBA would not accept that.

Comment: Myabe just `If Cells(l, 2).Value = 0`?

Comment: When I debug, the errors refer to the expressions of the For-loops and If-blocks which contain the offset.
E.g.  `Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Value = Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Offset(5, -2)` works fine, but `Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Value = Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Offset(5, -2) - Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Offset(22, -2)` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of closing this issue, I figured out what was wrong and I post it to help others keep in mind that when your code seems okay then there might be something wrong the data you are processing.

In my case, parts of the initial dataset was missing and as a consequence the calculations would do not perform due to ERRORs.

I had to add inside my IF-block `On error Resume Next`, while I thought that it would be a better practice to store the values of the cells to variables. This kept my code going on.
I read that this is not the best practice to handle errors in VBA, but it worked for the time being.

Then, I had to `Set` the range and the start_cell, as @SJR mentioned and also add `.value` to the `Application.Sum`. So my code alterations are reflected here:

```
For l = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(l, 2).Value = "00:00:00" Then
        Set start_cell = Cells(l, intensity_column) 'I added "Set"
        Set rng = Range(start_cell, start_cell.Offset(23, 0)) 'I added "Set"
        Cells(l, lastCol + 1).Value = Application.Sum(rng) 'I added ".Value"
    End If
Next l

'I create the column with the subtracted value of hour "22:00" from the value of hour "05:00", which should be written at row with hour "00:00"

Dim sm5, sm22 As Variant 'I created two more variables

For l = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(l, 2).Value = "00:00:00" Then
        On Error Resume Next 'I added a command how to handle the Error due to unclean data
        sm5 = Cells(l, lastCol-1).Offset(5, -2)
        sm22 = Cells(l, lastCol-1).Offset(22, -2)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(l, lastCol + 2).Value = sm5 - sm22
    End If
Next l
```